# Data binding json objects to xaml c#

Tags: c#, json, xaml, data-binding, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that implements crud methods and my client is windows 8 app.
I'm trying to bind the web api response: json objects (players) to my xaml and I only want to have the name of these players, I tried some stuff but I only get the name of the object (Common.Models.Player).

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var server = "http://localhost:1504/api";
        var service = System.IO.Path.Combine(server, "Players");
        var players = await GetAsync<IEnumerable<Common.Models.Player>>(new Uri(service));
        Isplayers.ItemsSource = players;
    }

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var http = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var response = await http.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.StatusCode != Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode.Ok)
            {
                throw new Exception(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
            string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }

    }
```

here's my xaml:

```
 <ListBox Name="Isplayers" ItemsSource="{Binding players}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NamePlayer}" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I'm new with manipulating json, any help !

Comment: You shouldn't use `System.IO.Path` to combine two URI's, use the `Uri` class constructor that takes a base `Uri` and a relative path: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So what you're getting is the default implementation of the ToString() method on the Player instance (probably not what you want).  In order for this to work NamePlayer the property needs to the be the actual string you want to display.  (But I don't see the code for that in the question to help further...)

Comment: @kirkSpaziani what code you need to see, the models of the player?

Comment: I'm confused about what's going on actually.  You're setting the ItemsSource in the code behind - but in the xaml attempting a bind?  The binding is likely overridden - (makes sense given your output)...  So does the Player object have a NamePlayer property that's a string?  If it does - this should work....